How to fill empty space before a CSS column break?
I have a multi-column CSS layout with specific column breaks:
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#fdx-reader {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 75px 30px 35px 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    column-width: calc(100vw - 60px);
    column-gap: 60px;
}
#fdx-reader > * {
    break-inside: avoid;
}
.fdx-chapter {
    break-before: column;
    margin-top: 0;
}

In this HTML:
<div id="fdx-reader">
    <div class="fdx-chapter" data-chapter-id="1">
        <p>Content of chapter 1...</p>
        <div class="chapter-end"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="fdx-chapter" data-chapter-id="2">
        <p>Content of chapter 2...</p>
        <div class="chapter-end"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Which renders pages in a book, where one column is one page.
Our break-before: column; in .fdx-chapter breaks the content to the next column, so each chapter starts on a new page, as you can see in the image below:

However, as you can see in the image, the page before the .fdx-chapter column break doesn't fill the entire page.
The image below has the current last page of the chapter on the left, and the ideal last page of the chapter on the right. It calculates the difference between content and fills to the bottom of the page, minus margin:

I've tried adding:
 .chapter-end { 
     padding-bottom: 100%;
 }

But it doesn't provide a consistent result. In some chapters it spills over to another column, while in other chapters it works well.
Is there a JS or CSS way to fill the last page of each chapter, from the end of our chapter content to the bottom of the viewport?

have you tried page-break-after: always? PS, wrap chapters in a <section> which si semantically correct and then you can apply that property to every section.

@tacoshy It's unclear how break-after would resolve this, as I need to content fill the remaining area for a percentage of chapter calculation.

what do you mean with that? fill with what? IS this a book supposed to be a @print media?

@tacoshy Not print media, we store chapter progress by chapter ID and percentage of chapter due to primary user interaction through scroll content across devices, therefore we need a consistent way to calculate correct page by chapter ID and percentage to render page view mode. When a page doesn't have content filled to the end before a column break, the percentage to page calculation is incorrect.

Could you explain a bit more how the percentage you require is calculated? There may be a different way of achieving what you want that doesn’t do “filling”.

you should assign body min-height: 100vh
and then fdx-chapter shoud be given:
height: 100%

or
height: calc(100vh - /*margin from body*/)

